# How to use Java to print out letters?

Tags: java

The code must allow the user to type in a four letter combination of T,I,L and translate that into the word TILT. However, the code must print out the word TILT using - and |. The - is for the top parts of the letters T and I and the bottom of L. | is used for everything else. There needs to be if and else statements and int line statements.

Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this? Anything helps!
This is what I have so far, it runs only up to where it prints back what the user has entered but it does not print it out using - and |.

```
import.java.util.Scanner
public class letters
{
private char letter1, letter2, letter3, letter4;
public void readIn()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter four letters that consist of any combination of T, I, or L");

    letter1 = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    letter2 = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    letter3 = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    letter4 = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

    System.out.println("You entered the following:" + letter1 +letter2 + letter3 + letter4);


}
// This method tracks which line to print out at a given time
public void printOut()
 {
     for (int line = 0; line , 5; line++)
          drawLine(line);
     }

 public void drawLine(int Line)
   {
    if (line == 0)
   {
      if (letter1 == 'T' || letter1 == 'I')
          System.out.println("-----");
       else
      System.out.println("|");
    }   
       else if (line < 4)
   {
       if(letter1 == 'L')
      System.out.println("  |  ")
      }
         if (line == 4)

         {
           if(letter1 == 'T')
           System.out.println("  |  ");

          else
             System.out.println("-----");
          }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This suggestion doesn’t fit exactly into your program, but I am sure you can make it fit. The code is at the bottom.

When I call `printOut()` with argument `"TILT"`, it prints:

```
----- ----- |     ----- 
  |     |   |       |   
  |     |   |       |   
  |     |   |       |   
  |   ----- -----   |
```

If you want, you can put the string arrays into a `HashMap<Character, String[]>` for easier lookup instead of the switch/case statement.

```
static String[] linesT = { "-----",
                           "  |  ",
                           "  |  ",
                           "  |  ",
                           "  |  " };

static String[] linesI = { "-----",
                           "  |  ",
                           "  |  ",
                           "  |  ",
                           "-----" };

static String[] linesL = { "|    ",
                           "|    ",
                           "|    ",
                           "|    ",
                           "-----" };

private static void printOut(String letters) {
    for (int line = 0; line < 5; line++) {
        for (int letter = 0; letter < letters.length(); letter++)
            switch (letters.charAt(letter)) {
                case 'T':
                    System.out.print(linesT[line]);
                    break;
                case 'I':
                    System.out.print(linesI[line]);
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    System.out.print(linesL[line]);
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot print letter " + letters.charAt(letter));
            }
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Khali If you're not familiar with the switch statement, you can write it as `if (letters.charAt(letter) == 'T') { System.out.print(linesT[line]); }` and then `else if (letters.charAt(letter) == 'I') {System.out.print(linesI[line]); }` and so forth

Comment: @Ole V.V. So when you created the project did you create a project and from there a class that contained a main and a separate class for the actual code? Sorry I am brand new to this and I'm just trying to learn as much as I can. Thanks!

Comment: Your interest in design is a sound one. I only see now that you must have your `main` method in a different class from `letters` (which ought to be `Letters` with a capital L since it’s a class). I didn’t really respect your design when I answered, sorry. Since I didn’t need a complete program, just one method and the three declarations that the method needed, I was lazy, used a project I already have for smaller SO things (really dirty), created a new class with both `main()` and the code you see. A poor example am I.